# Why does my app take so much space?

Tags: java, android

I'm finishing my android first app and I'm wondering why does it take so much space. It just has few activities with WebView and TextView so it should take around 1MB (like the .apk does) but definitely not 12... I've looked around but haven't seen any good reason, compressing images doesn't help much either, please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this question is within the scope of Stack Overflow. I think your answer is over at Android Enthusiasts though!

https://android.stackexchange.com/a/107204

To paraphrase, the APK is compressed version of your app. So it may be 1MB, but once decompressed on the phone, it may take 12 MB of space. If you are worrying about your app's size because you want the download to be as small as possible, then it shouldn't be a problem. It downloads from the Play Store as 1 MB.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio, go to File-Project Structure and verify the default Dependencies already included in your project. It seems you're not using support-appcompat-v7, for example. If you make your apk without this dependency you will get your apk compressed by hundreds of kbytes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm actually using appcompat so removing that gave me build errors but I managed to remove some other dependency.